# Paginated Posts - Social Media Buttons Share First Page URL

Tags: posts, urls, buttons

I currently have the HTML5 Facebook, Twitter and G+ share buttons inserted into my single.php in WordPress, so it appears on all my post pages.

Everything works great until I write a very long article split into multiple pages using the nextpage tag.

The problem is if the reader is on page 3, and wanted to share the article, when they click the share button, they are prompted to share the URL of that particular page - nameofsite.com/nameofpost/3 and not of the first/main page of the article - http://www.nameofsite.com/nameofpost, so I am left with many post shares for different pages of the same article! Frown | :-(

Is there anyway I can overcome this for all my paginated posts?

Thank you,

James

Edit: I have used the following HTML:

```
<div class="post-sharing">
 <ul>
  <li class="share-title"><p>Share This Post</p></li>
  <li><div id="fb-root"></div><div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button_count"></div></li>
  <li class="share-twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a></li>
  <li class="share-google"><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble"></div></li>
  <li class="share-linkedin"><script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script></li>
  <li class="share-comments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('No Comments', 'One Comment', '%' );?></a>
</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I have then entered in the following in .js file called nbzsocial.js:

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=225721797619871";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Which I have placed in a js folder in my child theme and enqueued in my functions PHP with this:

```
function wpse_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nbz-social', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/nbzsocial.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_scripts' );
```

Thank you for getting back to me so quickly, I have had no luck on the WordPress forums and Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please add the code you are currently using for your share buttons.

Comment: Added in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Is that share javascript getting called before or after the next page tag? Presumably, if its a shortcode, you want to be inserting it after the next page tag?

Comment: No matter where I place the HTML in my single.php or content.php, when you click on the Facebook Share button the pop up window prompts you to share the URL of the page you are on - Some of my articles are 20 pages long and I want each of those pages to share the URL of the first page of the post - examplesite.com/nameofpost and not examplesite.com/nameofpost/3

Comment: Where is it getting the URL to share? I notice  <li class="share-comments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> which would grab the comments link, but if you edit the plugin file can you set it to get the_permalink?

Comment: Mate, get in! Didnt even think of it that way!! Changed the list item for facebook above to: `<li><div id="fb-root"></div><div class="fb-share-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-type="button_count"></div></li>` and it works like a charm. Thank you so much, so simple

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Please mark as correct?